# Using feature, story and task branches?

Tags: git, architecture, branch, azure-devops, branching-strategy

We are using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) which have epics, features, stories and down to tasks. We will also follow [git dmz flow](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/9f2f91085607a4859a66) in which development happens in feature branches. We want to use VSTS structure but not breaking the principles and benefits of git dmz flow.

I was thinking of having a **feature branch** that will be branched out to **story branch** and story branch that will be branch out to **task branch** (where the actual dev work happens). Is this not add too much overhead for the dev team? Can automation help in this?

I am considering to use story branches like feature branches (in git dmz flow context) wherein, when a story is done, you can make a PR going to dmz branch (but it kind of destroys the structure in VSTS/agile structure?)

I believed that tasks can be finished not more than a day so task branches should be short-lived. I also assume that features take days to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have bundled the work items and branches together.

In Git DMZ Flow, it talks about how to use different branches to build/release your projects efficiently. And this article has no business with WIT (work item type).

On the other hand, branches and work items usually is not one-to-one correspondence but one-to-many relationship. That means what you prepare to develop on feature branch can be listed by detail operations in work items.

For example, there has a feature branch which need to export reports for a company, let call the branch name is `feature/reporting` here. Now you can list detail works for this feature in work items as:

```
  |___ daily report                (User story)
  |         |___ template design   (task)
  |         |___ function develop  (task)
  |         |___ QA test           (task)
  |___ monthly report              (User story)
  |         |___ …                 (task)
  |___ yearly report               (User story)
            |___ …                 (task)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yup it seems so that's why it made me a little confused. I think we are going to branching out from feature branch to task branch and will not use story branch. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: It's not necessary to create so many branches. As the user stories and tasks listed in above example, all of them just support to develop the feature of `feature/reporting` smoothly. So you just need to checkout feature branch from `master`, that's enough.